# Azure devop- subscription does not send email to me

Tags: azure-devops

I'm a tester and typically create bug in Azure devop. I want to receive an email on work items that were created by myself AND (comment is posted OR assign to any members) BUT it does not work if work item is changed to another person.

My subscription as following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, you only define the `History Changes` in Notification.

The History field represents the **Comment** field in the work item. So no notification will be sent when the assign to changes.

To meet your requirements, you can add an filter: `Assign To ->  Changes` and set the relationship as `Or`.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: May I know if the answer can help you solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check this site for a long time. It works with me now. Thank you so much